# Executing an inner function by returning the function name

Tags: javascript, object, literals

I would like to execute the inner function but I am struggling to understand why it comes back as not defined

```
object.method2();

var object = {
    method1 : function(){
        return function(){
            innerFunction();
        }
    },

    method2 : function(){
        function innerFunction(){
            alert('I am showing as not defined but I want to be executed')
        }

        executeInnerFunction = object.method1()
        executeInnerFunction();
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript has *lexical* scoping---code can only see variables declared in its scope (function) or any ancestor scope up the syntax tree.  Since `innerFunction` is declared in the scope of `method2`, and `method2` is syntactically not an ancestor of `method1`, you can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

innerFunction is only known in method2 since it is declared in the scope of method2.
If you want to have access from method1, you may declare innerFunction over this :
`this.innnerFunction = function(){}`, so that `object.innerFunction()` can be called.

If you do not want to expose innerFunction as a public method of object you may want to use closure  :

```
function doObject(){
 function innerFunction(){alert('yihou');}
 return {
  method1:function(){innerFunction();},
  method2:function(){}
 };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment also isn't right, I think. Do this instead:

```
executeInnerFunction = object.method1;
```

You want to store a reference to the method, not the results of calling the method once.

Beyond that, see what ngn had to say.

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered the scope issue, but you are also trying to call `object.method2()`
before it exists.

Function declarations are processed before code is executed so you can call declared functions higher up the code than where they are written, however *object.method2* is created by assignment, so *object* doesn't have a *method2* property until the assignement code is executed, which is after the call.